# bash / sed / awk Remove or gsub timestamp pattern from text file

Tags: bash, date, datetime, awk, sed

I have a text file like this:

```
1/7/2017 12:53  DROP TABLE table1                                                   
1/7/2017 12:53  SELECT  

1/7/2017 12:55  --UPDATE #dat_recency SET
Select * from table 2
into table 3;
```

I'd like to remove all of the timestamp patterns (`M/D/YYYY HH:MM`, `M/DD/YYYY HH:MM`, `MM/D/YYYY HH:MM`, `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM`).  I can find the patterns using `grep` but can't figure out how to use `gsub`. Any suggestions?

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
DROP TABLE table1                                                   
SELECT  

--UPDATE #dat_recency SET
Select * from table 2
into table 3;
```

Comment: no perl available. on a windows box, i'm actually using the bash editor that comes with git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `sed` command to remove data/time stamps from line start:

```
sed -i.bak -E 's~([0-9]{1,2}/){2}[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} *~~' file

cat file

DROP TABLE table1
SELECT

--UPDATE #dat_recency SET
Select * from table 2
into table 3;
```

Comment: Maybe shorter `sed -E 's~([0-9]{1,2}/){2}[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} *~~'`

Comment: Yes that will be more concise

Answer (score 2):

Use the default space separator, make first and second columns to empty string and then print the whole line.

```
awk '/^[0-9]/{$1=$2="";gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, "")} !/^[0-9]/{print}' sample.csv
```

the command checks each line whether starts with numeric or not, if it is replace the first 2 columns with empty strings and remove leading spaces; otherwise print the original line.

output:

```
DROP TABLE table1
SELECT

--UPDATE #dat_recency SET
Select * from table 2
into table 3;
```

Comment: This does not achieve OP's desired output. It leaves leading spaces and it clobbers `Select ` and `into` on the last two lines.

Comment: @Jordan thanks for your comment. OP modified his question, there was no query.  I have updated my answer for the latest question